# Drupal 7 Views 3 Contextual Filter - preview works as expected, the actual page not, why?

Tags: 7, views

**Background:**

Drupal 7.2, Views 7.x-3.0-rc1

I have a view with a single Contextual Filter, 'User: Full Name'. ('User: Full Name' is a field added to the user, stores the full name of the user, like 'Peter Jackson Junior'.) In this filter's settings, under 'More', 'Case in path' is set to 'Lower' and 'Transform spaces to dashes in URL' is enabled, because the format of the path would be like this: 'site/team/peter-jackson-junior'. 'No results behavior' is set to 'Global: Text', contains 'No such user'. So the result of the view would be the profile of the user that has full name equals to argument in url.

**Problem:**

On the view settings page, when I test it through the preview, it works perfectly, I enter 'peter-jackson-junior' and it returns the profile of 'Peter Jackson Junior'. But, when I would like to see it in practice, and enter the url 'site/team/peter-jackson-junior' (this is actually also shown on the view preview area) in the browser url bar, I get back
'The requested page could not be found.'.

Actually, if I 'provide default value' 'when the filter value is not in the url' that is 'fixed', like 'another-full-name' it works on both the preview and the actual page (so 'site/team' gives back the profile of 'Another Full Name'), but 'site/team/another-full-name' gives back 'The requested page could not be found.' again.

**Question:**

What could be the problem? Could this be a bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the answer to the problem...

There are path aliases to nodes that were deleted before, and accidentally those aliases look exactly like how the view with arguments should look like. So, there were an alias of 'team/peter-jackson-junior' to 'node/xyz', this overridden the path to the view, but 'node/xyz' was deleted and so it is natural that it gives back 'The requested page could not be found.'.